# Calling a function from markup to determine visibility

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this code in my `aspx` page:

```
<asp:Localize ID="locWanAddressGatewayRouter" meta:resourcekey="locWanAddressGatewayRouterRc1" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" Visible="<% MethodOne() %>">
    WAN Address of Gateway Router
</asp:Localize>
```

I want to be able to call the `MethodOne()`:

```
protected bool MethodOne()
{
    // returns a bool true or false
}
```

However, I get an `unexpected` error when attempting to enter this `aspx` page.  Is this the correct way to a call a C# function on server side?  Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

Use the correct in-line block

`<%` is for a code block.
`<%=` is for an expression - which is what you need.

```
Visible="<%= methodOne() %>"
```

Answer (score 1):

At a minimum, the method `methodOne` would have to be public I think; I don't believe protected gets the job done.  Also, markup expressions directly to the UI in web forms behaves differently than markup defined of a property to controls.  I don't know, since it's not a binding expression, how web forms reacts.  Note that expressoins use <%= %> notation to output the value, which is what your code above was missing.

At a minimum, you can do it from code-behind:

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
    locWanAddressGatewayRouter.Visible = methodOne();
}
```

Which would do the same thing.

Comment: it shouldn't be public, as class that will be generated based on aspx page will inherit code behind class, so it will have access to protected members

Comment: OK, I couldn't remember.  THX

Answer (score 0):

On your aspx :

```
<asp:Localize ID="locWanAddressGatewayRouter" meta:resourcekey="locWanAddressGatewayRouterRc1" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
   WAN Address of Gateway Router
  </asp:Localize>
```

On your CS:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        locWanAddressGatewayRouter.Visible = methodOne();
    }

    private bool methodOne()
    {
        return true;
    }
```

Try this this will work. Reason of this error may be is your aspx tag is runat server and a function returning the value is also on server side so while rendering control CLR is not able to evaluate methodOne().

This thing will work fine in case of HTML tag if that html is not runat=server.